# Quote and slash issue in PHP

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string, magic-quotes-gpc

Every time i try to update my textarea and inside the textarea I add a quote `"`, after i update i get 1 `\`, i update again i get 3 slashes `\\\`, again 5 slashes and so on.
Tried adding in php ini the the 3 codes to disable the magic quotes but nothing:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

Added also in the root folder and the folder where the file is located. Also tried this
https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php example 2 and first comment and still nothing.

This is my code:

PHP

```
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
$viewtopic = $_GET['viewtopic'];
if ($_POST['edit'] && strip_tags($_POST['topictext'])){
  $viewtopic = $_POST['id'];
  $topictext=mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['topictext']));
  $title=mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['title']));
  mysql_query("UPDATE topics SET topictext=".quote_smart($topictext).", title=".quote_smart($title)." WHERE id=".quote_smart($viewtopic)."");
  echo "You have updated your topic!";
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea name="topictext" rows="2" cols="20" id="main_tbContent" class="TextBox" style="height:128px;width:99%;"><? echo str_replace("\\r\\n","\r\n",$rows['topictext']); ?></textarea><br />
```

Comment: what does quote_smart() do ??

Comment: Quote_smart is integrated in the script. When i remove `quote_smart()` it seams that the loop of creating 2 more slashes every update stops but it still echo's 3 slashes.

Comment: don't forget to mysql_real_escape_string $_POST['id'] as well... though you are expecting (hoping) you are going to get a numeric value there, in fact you can also get anything else there , making sql injection possible

Comment: I can't believe this question werent closed at sight as a duplicate. Stack Overflow is a VERY strange place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, in my code for my database entries, this is what I do. Let me start by saying that I always send via POST method to avoid browser url complications.

When I get the POST data, this is my code.

```
    $ID = 1;
    $DATA = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST['data']));
    $FIELD = lifename;
    $DBQUERY = "UPDATE `lifetable` SET `$FIELD` = '$DATA' WHERE `id` = $ID";
    $DBRESULT = $MYSQLI->query($DBQUERY);
```

When I ask for the information back in a select query, I do not do anything special, all I do is a normal fetch_assoc or fetch_array with no functions at all. This always works for both input values and textareas.

This should be yours:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE topics SET topictext='".htmlentities(addslashes($topictext))."', title='".htmlentities(addslashes($title))."' WHERE id='$viewtopic'");
```

And do not forget your single quotes when passing text data as a value in mysql. I added them.

I am currently using this on my local site.

Also, please remove all instances of `mysql_real_escape_string` functions.

Comment: addslashes is not adequate for sanitising db inputs

Comment: could you please help me based on my example I am not getting it exactly.

Comment: Um, clearly his code is adding extra slashes because they are there. Therefor, to remove the extra slashes, addslashes() will removed the extras for the most part.

Comment: It is hard to know without knowing what your quote_smart function does. Here I will update my answer, give me a minute :)

Comment: It seams that `.quote_smart` is some kind of predefined function in mysql/php. I tried searching for the function with dreamweaver and no results regarding a normal php function.

Comment: Remove all `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Trust me, it is still 100% safe!

Comment: Like for example instead of `$topictext=mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['topictext']));` I do `$topictext=$_POST['topictext'];`

Comment: No, it would be `$topictext=strip_tags($_POST['topictext']);`

Comment: Let me know if it works for you, it works for me all the time and on the go. Just make sure when you output your data from the database, you are outputting as is and do not change it in any way, use it raw right out of the fetcharray or fetch assoc call.

Comment: If this worked, can you please check the answer and help out the reputation. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it was because of the `mysql_real_escape_string` Thanks a lot.

Comment: no worries, adding slashes and htmlentities will make it so that no one can exit your code and start another. Some people will say otherwise, but I have yet to experience it.

Comment: stop giving bad advise  please addslashes(), is not sufficient

Comment: @YourCommonSense It tool me in the right direction, my problem it was because of `mysql_real_escape_string` so he deserves the up vote.

Comment: I prefer to use php pdo. PDO is an embedded extention that completely take care of the fear of injections. It separate the inputs  from the query and then insert it in db. 

The quote you are getting can be stripped out using js.  That means you need to screen out the data